# .swf file not displaying on website

Tags: html, flash

I need help embedding a .swf file onto my website. I have tried all kinds of code combinations. Here's what I currently have.

```
<div class="article_top_img">
     <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" >
            <param name="movie" value="myfile.swf">
            <param name="quality" value="high">
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
      <embed src="myfile.swf" quality="high" wmode="opaque" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="550" height="310"></embed>
    </object>
</div>
```

At the moment it's simply displaying the outline of the video.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to embed a swf file to HTML file with Adobe Dreamweaver application. Name of the swf file is t0.swf, it's located on the Desktop. It generated this code block:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="FlashID" title="swf file">
  <param name="movie" value="../Desktop/t0.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="7.0.70.0" />
  <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../Desktop/t0.swf" width="550" height="400">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="7.0.70.0" />
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

I've tried to view this html file with Google Chrome(version 30.0.1599.66 m), Mozilla Firefox (Version 24.0), Internet Explorer (Version 8) and Opera(Version 11.51). They all opened that html fine, swf animation starts playing just after opening the html. Also I've tried your code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" >
        <param name="movie" value="../Desktop/t0.swf">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
  <embed src="../Desktop/t0.swf" quality="high" wmode="opaque" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="550" height="310"></embed>
</object>
```

It also worked fine, except that internet explorer showed the swf animation a little bit smaller, but it worked. May be you should check your flash player plugin.

Comment: Thanks my friend but I managed to solve it by replacing the .swf file with a newer version I received from the client and it worked. Obviously the original version I was using might have been corrupt